# OpenCV 4.7 Java DescriptorExtractor and DescriptorMatcher are missing, no replacements found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to perform feature matching using this code from this question:
[OpenCV filtering ORB matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569386/opencv-filtering-orb-matches)

The ORB detection works, however DescriptorExtractor and DescriptorMatcher are no longer to be found in Feature2D and any of the imports

What are their replacements in OpenCV 4 and how do I use them?

OpenCV documentation offers no help or source code unfortunately
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d51/group__features2d__main.html

Thanks,

```
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
ORB detector = ORB.create();

DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);;
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

// First photo
Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, img1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

// Second photo
Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, img2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

// Matching

MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
MatOfDMatch filteredMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
```

Comment: undeclared crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-4-7-java-descriptorextractor-and-descriptormatcher-are-missing-what-do-i-use-instead-no-code-in-documenation/12332

Answer (score 0):

They just switched the code without updating any of the documentation,
as evident by DescriptorExtractor still being present in the documentation,

answers found in opencv forums

https://answers.opencv.org/question/210523/orb-implementation-in-javaandroid-package/

```
        ORB detector = ORB.create();
        detector.detect(img, keypoints1, descriptors1);
        detector.detectAndCompute(img, new Mat(), keypoints1, descriptors1);
```

The ExtractorMatcher is still in OpenCV 4.7 however, so it can still be used

Comment: not just in the old forum, also in the new forum: https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-4-7-java-descriptorextractor-and-descriptormatcher-are-missing-what-do-i-use-instead-no-code-in-documenation/12332